# How bind properties of generic bean to dynamically created swing components

Tags: java, swing, generics, dynamic, binding

I am making a property editor widget in Java. This widget will take in a java bean, make a copy of it, and dynamically create a JPanel with swing components to represent the fields in that bean. I would like to bind the swing components to the copy so that when the method getFinishedBean() is called, the copy is returned with its fields set to the values set in the swing components. I have tried to do this by looping through each field, determining its type, creating the appropriate JComponent for it, binding that component to the bean copy, and then adding the component to the panel. My issue is that the bean's properties don't seem to get bound.

This is the binding code:

```
if((component instanceof JCheckBox))
            {
                JCheckBox checkBox = (JCheckBox) component;

                BeanProperty<JCheckBox, Boolean> jCheckBoxBeanProperty = BeanProperty.create("selected");
                BeanProperty<T, Boolean> beanProperty = BeanProperty.create(field.getName());
                AutoBinding<JCheckBox, Boolean, T, Boolean> autoBinding = Bindings.createAutoBinding(
                        UpdateStrategy.READ,
                        checkBox, jCheckBoxBeanProperty, finishedBean, beanProperty);
                autoBinding.bind();

                builder.append(field.getName() + ":", checkBox);
            }
```

This code section has no compile errors or warnings, but the finishedBean's properties are not changed. I am very close, I just need to get the values from the JComponents into the finished bean.

Comment: assuming your binding framework is (better)beansbinding: the binding itself should work

Comment: I tried to run your example and, like Kleopatra, works flawless for me on BBB. Just note that running this code the finishedBean initial value is reset as the checkBox is set as source; I'd use a read/write strategy with the bean as source. If you're trying to check the values showing the panel again, you'll always get it reset.

Answer (score 0):

As kleopatra stated, the binding is adapted so it should be bound properly.

<strike>The property `selected` can't be bound directly on a `JCheckBox` (or any other component that extends from `JToggleButton` such as `JRadioButton`) since that property is not propagated on state changes. The binding installs a `PropertyChangeListener` but the component requires an `ItemListener` for listening to the changes.</strike>

You have two options:

- Extend the `JCheckBox` adding on creation an `ItemListener` that fires a property change for `selected` when an `ItemEvent` happens; or
- Use the bean property `action.selected` since, unlike the button itslef, the `Action` contained actually propagates the property change and thus can be bound.

I reccomend the second option since is cleaner.

Comment: the question looks like using (better)beansbinding - if so, the direct binding _is_ supported. (B)bb internally adapts the itemListener to a propertyChangeListener